# Is there any properties to select ListView items design time

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am creating an C# Windows Application. I could see there are many options to select the ListView items runtime. However i wanted to select few items to be selected in design time itself - i could not find any properties to set selection.

But in ASP.NET i could do selection by setting the listitem's selected property to true.

Comment: No there is no way to select items in the WinForms.Designer. However I don't see any problem in presetting some items in the forms load event. Why do you need to do it at design time?

Comment: I am actually migrating an asp.net application to windows for an internal purpose. In that webapplication a form having this default selections in design time.